# SSH and sudo over a pseudo-tty terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

I am trying to overcome some limitations in our environment to write up an authorized SSH file for passwordless ssh keys.

I am requiring to perform an ssh as a  to a target system, and then run a "sudo su - , and then update the service account authorized_keys with a key"

This eventually has to go onto my ansible scripts.

I am using "ssh -t user@target "sudo su - service-user" - which actually successfully gets me into a shell for service-user. But I am not able to figure out a way to pass along the file modify commands with the above.

Any tips or alternative options?

Note: I need to use "ssh -t" option as the requiretty is not set on target systems.

Cheers!

Comment: This question might get a better response on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: The sentence "*I am not able to figure out a way to pass along the file modify commands with the above.*" is incomprehensible.

Comment: hmm maybe i'll rephrase for those who need it - " Can someone help me identify the best way to do an ssh to target server and perform a sudo su and write a file"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what transport you're using you can use [ssh_args](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#ssh-args).

> OpenSSH is the default connection type for Ansible on OSes that are new enough to support ControlPersist. (This means basically all operating systems except Enterprise Linux 6 or earlier).

Then you can do something like this in your `ansible.cfg`:

```
ssh_args = -t -t
```

Which will force ansible to connect the same way you do manually.

Then in your playbook or together with the task where you need it specify `become` and `become_user`

```
- name: Some task
  debug: msg="this is a test"
  become: true
  become_user: someuser
```

Comment: well, the manual command itself does not work . I tried. ex. "ssh -t user@target "sudo su - service-user ; touch test" . I believe it is with the way the shell is spawned within the psuedo-tty.

Comment: Have you tried with multiple `-t`. From the manpage: "Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty"

Answer (score 0):

`su` has an option, `-c`, that allows you to pass along a command to execute instead of launching a new shell.

> -c, --command=COMMAND
>       pass a single COMMAND to the shell with -c

However, you're authenticating with `sudo`, which already does this by default; you can just cut `su` out of the command entirely:

```
ssh -t user@target "sudo -u service-user <your-command>"
```

To go one step further, you note that you're planning on putting this into an Ansible playbook.  If so, you probably shouldn't be spending too much time trying to do this manually - Ansible will handle running commands remotely (that's one of its primary features, after all), and has [a module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html) for modifying the `authorized_keys` file.